# How do I set the global regional setting for decimal separator to a comma or a period?

Tags: vb.net, regional-settings

Is it possible to programmatically and PERMANENTLY reset the global regional setting for the decimal separator symbol from a comma to a period? Answers for VB code are highly appreciated.

Comment: If you're talking about system-wide then that's really not something that an application should be doing. If the user wants to change their Windows settings then they should do that through Windows or their admin should do it via the domain. In general, an application developer should write their code to honour whatever system settings happen to be in place at the time. If your app needs to serialise data and must use a specific format for that, choose the option that makes the most sense and document that.

Comment: The question is not so trivial; if an application purpose is essentially to exchange info with other system, via some protocols, where numbers have the decimal point, it's painful if you have to wrestle with the tendency of vb.net / csharp to honor the OS settings. So I up-voted the question. Consider this code snippet:  Dim culture As New CultureInfo("en-US"), Dim enFormat As NumberFormatInfo = culture.NumberFormat, Dim value As Double = Double.Parse(s, enFormat); now s contains "3.45678", but the parse function still fails, because it expects a comma. As I said, it's painful.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the culture of your application (on the `Load` event of your form):

```
Application.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("EN-US")
```

or

```
Application.ChangeCulture("EN-US")
```

**Note:** You shouldn't change the system-wide settings through your application. You can use one of the codes above to change the settings only in your application.